# How to get term by name with parent id?

Tags: terms

So I have two menus which has childs with the same name. How to get term by name but from specified parent?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and specify `name` and `parent`.

```
$name = 'Flowers';
$parent_id = 42;

$args = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'parent' => $parent_id
);
$terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );
```

Comment: Strange, but `get_terms` returns only 1 value, but in database I have 3...  I use like this: `get_terms('gp_hubs', ['name' => 'Vilniaus miestas/rajonas'])` and get only one... Here is my db https://www.dropbox.com/s/rn8ru7ubcejdyhl/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-02-01%2000.46.42.png?dl=0

Comment: do all of them have posts assigned? you have to set `hide_empty` to `false` if you want terms that have no posts.